# Importar DLL Itaucripto no VB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, vb.net, visual-basic-6

Olá,
Estou implantando a segunda via de boleto itaú, porém estou tento que trabalhar com ASP.NET VB e não tenho muito conhecimento nesta linguagem.
Fiz tudo certo e está funcionando localmente, porem quando subo para minha hospedagem na Locaweb recebo o seguinte erro

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not create an object of type 'Itaucripto.cripto'.]
```

Este erro acontece porque a itaucripto.dll não está instalada em minha hospedagem, entrei em contato com o suporte e disseram que eles não fazem a instalação da DLL no servidor e que eu devo color a DLL dentro do meu projeto e referencia-la na aplicação.
Como faço para importar está DLL na minha aplicação ?

Answer (score 2):

[Primeiro gere um Assembly Interop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/697w37zd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Essa DLL é um Assembly COM, não compatível diretamente com o Framework .NET. Depois inclua esse Assembly no seu código para ter acesso às interfaces COM.

Feito isso, [é preciso configurar o projeto para usar a DLL livre de registro na interface do Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx).

Há, ainda, uma segunda alternativa a partir do Framework 3.5, que é compilando a DLL Interop no Build do projeto. Dentro do seu arquivo `.csproj`, é necessário colocar o seguinte:

```
<Project ...>
  <ItemGroup>
    <COMFileReference Include="itaucripto.dll">
      <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMFileReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[Há mais detalhes nesta resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8887087/1314276).

Comment: Beleza, vou tentar a segunda alternativa estou com Framework 4.5, Obrigado!!

Comment: Utilizando a segunda opção eu preciso gerar um Assembly Interop ?

Comment: Não, a ideia é que o MSBuild gera isso por você. Você só precisa fazer a declaração no web.config.

Comment: Meu web.config não está reconhecendo a propriedade <ItemGroup>, sabe o que pode ser ? "Erro de Configuração    Não é possível ler a seção de configuração 'ItemGroup' porque falta uma declaração de seção"

Comment: @DanielGregatto Erro meu. Não é no `web.config`. É dentro do `.csproj`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer a referência da Dll utilizando DllImport. No topo do seu código digite:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
```

Depois coloque a Dll no source do seu código, isso é bastante importante, caso a sua Dll fique em uma pasta que ele não encontre, não vai funcionar. Por fim, é só invocar a Dll.

```
<System.Runtime.InteropService.DllImport("SUADLL.dll", _
SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
```